# How to best deal with a feature relating to what type of expert labelled the data that becomes unavailable at point of classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, feature-selection

Essentially I have a data set, that has a feature vector, and label indicating whether it is spam or non-spam.

To get the labels for this data, 2 distinct types of expert were used each using different approaches to evaluate the item, the type of expert used then also became a feature in the vector.

Training and then testing on a separate portion of the data has achieved a high degree accuracy using a Random Forest algorithm.

However, it is clear now that, the feature describing the expert who made the label will not be available in a live environment. So I have tried a number of approaches to reflect this:

1. Remove the feature from the set and retrain and test
2. Split the data into 2 distinct sets based on the feature, and then train and test 2 separate classifiers
3. For the test data, set the feature in question all to the same value

With all 3 approaches, the classifiers have dropped from being highly accurate, to being virtually useless.

So I am looking for any advice or intuitions as to why this has occurred and how I might approach resolving it so as to regain some of the accuracy I was previously seeing?

To be clear I have no background in machine learning or statistics and am simply using a third party c# code library as a black box to achieve these results.

Comment: Maybe you'll get better answers on http://stats.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've completely overfit to the "who labeled what" feature (and combinations of this feature with other features). You can find out for sure by inspecting the random forest's [feature importances](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4928-understanding-variable-importances-in-forests-of-randomized-trees) and checking whether the annotator feature ranks high. Another way to find out is to let the annotators check each other's annotations and compute an agreement score such as [Cohen's kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen's_kappa). A low value, say less than .5, indicates disagreement among the annotators, which makes machine learning very hard.

Since the feature will not be available at test time, there's no easy way to get the performance back.